# SDL apps don't run on other computers

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, codeblocks

I've just written an app in C++ using SDL 1.2.15 and SDL_image 1.2.12 libraries. It works on my computer but whenever I send *.exe to my friends (of course with all *.dll files from SDL libraries and images that program needs) they say that nothing happens (no message, no error, etc.). The content of the program doesn't matter as every SDL app written by me create such a problem.

I'm working on Code::Blocks 10.05 on Windows XP (as my friends). Obviously I've sent the release version.

I discovered that my program doesn't run in the compatibility mode with Windows NT and lower.

Comment: did you have the sdl dll files in the same directory as your exe when building?

Comment: Nope, they are in the same directory as cpp file.

Comment: does it not work on all the friends' PCs or just a few of them?

Comment: I haven't tried it on exactly all my friends' computers but it didn't worked on all PC I tried.

Comment: you should probably install some "clean" Windows installation on virtual machine locally, and try with it to figure it out..

Answer (score 2):

If application appears to don't even start, you can use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check whether all the static dependencies are fulfilled. It will show you if there are any missing dlls. If all dependencies seem to be fulfilled (no error in dll list), you can use `Profile` command from the main menu to profile the startup of the application.

Profiling will show you if there are any issue with dynamic dependencies (dlls loaded via COM or explicit calls to `LoadLibrary`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just discovered my mistake. I determined the width and height of my SDL_Surface (with SDL_SetVideoMode()) to fit my screen dimensions. When the function wanted to do the same on screen with other dimensions it returned NULL thus crashing all app.
Thanks for concern.